# Error handling in controller with reactor and micronaut

Tags: java, project-reactor, micronaut

In this controller I'm trying to catch an exception called `RedisException.class` which is thrown from messageService and instead return a http response 503 to the user.

MessageService method signature is

```
public Mono<Void> process(Request request) {}
```

Here's what I have in the controller (doesn't compile)

```
@Post
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "503", description = "Unable to submit to Redis for processing")
public Mono<MutableHttpResponse<Response>> acceptMsg(@Body @NonNull Request request) {
    return messageService.process(request)
            .thenReturn(HttpResponse.accepted().body(new Response()))
            .onErrorReturn(HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body("Unable to submit to Redis for processing"));
}
```

How do I allow .onErrorReturn() to accept a string instead of the type `Request` which it is currently bound to?

Comment: noticed that you defined thenReturn operation previous , so whatever the ```process``` return value upstream , the downstream  would receive the type of Response stream , if you would like to receive a error string as type of stream , you can try the following code snippet
``` messageService.process(request) .onErrorReturn(e-> e instanceof RedisException, "There is something wrong in redis")  ```